# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

With the below code I keep getting the following errors:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[csp_WellTestValidationResultsTEST_GetData]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[csp_WellTestValidationResultsTEST_GetData]

DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(max);       --Column Name that Maps to AF Attribute
DECLARE @ColumnValue varchar(max);      --Specific Value for that Column
DECLARE @LeftNumber varchar(50) = SUBSTRING(@ColumnValue,0,CHARINDEX('-',@ColumnValue,0));
DECLARE @RightNumber varchar(50) = SUBSTRING(@ColumnValue,CHARINDEX('-',@ColumnValue,0)+1,LEN(@ColumnValue));
DECLARE @API varchar(50) = SUBSTRING(@ColumnName,0,CHARINDEX('-',@ColumnName,0));


AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF (@ColumnName = 'API14-2')
       Exec('Select * from dbo.SSIS_RTRM_WellTestValidationResults where '+@API+' = '+@LeftNumber+' OR '+@API+' = '+@RightNumber+' order by TestDate Desc')   
Else 
    Select * From dbo.SSIS_RTRM_WellTestValidationResults where WellId = ''
  END
```

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, the `declare`s go after the `begin`.

Answer (score 1):

To pass variables to a sporc, use the syntax create procedure {schema.procedure_name} {@variable1} {variable1_data_type}, {@variable2} {variable2_data_type}
AS
{SPROC here}

If you want a default value for a variable which also makes the variable optional, {variable} {vairable_data_type} = {variable_default_value}

This is only for variables you pass when calling the sproc.  Any variables defined in the sproc you declare in the sproc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[csp_WellTestValidationResultsTEST_GetData]
@ColumnName varchar(max);       --Column Name that Maps to AF Attribute
,@ColumnValue varchar(max);      --Specific Value for that Column
AS
DECLARE @LeftNumber varchar(50) = SUBSTRING(@ColumnValue,0,CHARINDEX('-',@ColumnValue,0));
DECLARE @RightNumber varchar(50) = SUBSTRING(@ColumnValue,CHARINDEX('-',@ColumnValue,0)+1,LEN(@ColumnValue));
DECLARE @API varchar(50) = SUBSTRING(@ColumnName,0,CHARINDEX('-',@ColumnName,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

As 'Gordon Linoff' pointed out, your create procedure statements should be

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[csp_WellTestValidationResultsTEST_GetData]

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(max);       --Column Name that Maps to AF Attribute
........
```

On another note, I am not sure if you can declare and assign value in the same statement as you did, it might need to be replaced to:

```
DECLARE @LeftNumber varchar(50);
SET @LeftNumber = SUBSTRING(@ColumnValue,0,CHARINDEX('-',@ColumnValue,0));
```

And so on

Comment: Declare and assign depends on the version of SQL Server.